# Do all file structures need to be identical to use GitHub?

Tags: git, github

We are finally beginning to use GitHub for our web development workflow. I know, welcome to the 19th century, right?

We are trying to get our existing projects setup and I ran into a problem with folder structures that I don't know how to deal with.

On our local development machines we create a folder called website-A.com. Inside that folder are all the files to make the website - it's the root.

On our production server the root is at /var/blah/sites/website-A.com/html/

On GitHub our repository is called website-A.com

I've run `git init` on the /var/blah/sites/website-A.com/html/, the root folder on our production server.

When perform a `git clone git@github.com:myaccount/website-A.com.git` while in the /html (root) folder on the server git places a 'website-A.com' folder inside the root.

My question is, how do I get my master branch on the production server to synchronize with GitHub without my git command creating a new directory called "website-A.com" in the /html folder on the production server?

Do we need to alter our folder structures on our local machines? Is there an easy way to create this html folder on GitHub or do we need to redo everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conceptual problem more so than a Git problem.

You're munging two things here - the place of source control and your deploy scheme.

Your source control layout should be *independent* of your deploy scheme; you can place your files into very different locations on deploy, or have files that don't normally exist in your development suddenly appear on deploy (think dynamically populated images, generated PDFs, etc).

The layout of your project should conform to the way you're used to working.  That style shouldn't matter at all, and it should be done on a *developer's* machine, **not** the main server.  That particular layout is what you want to push to GitHub.  Yes, **this** particular layout must be homogeneous to all developers, or conflicts (and/or pain) ensues.

When it's time to deploy to the main server, you would want to pull your changes in from upstream on the remote server, then work out a packaging and deploy scheme that best suits your needs.  If it's JavaScript + HTML based, there are build systems (like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)) that can get you over the hurdle of building out the necessary artifacts, and potentially moving them over to where you need to deploy them.

Comment: Makoto, thank you but I'm new enough to this that your answer seems ambiguous to me. I'm sure it's my lack of knowledge that's the issue here.What I understand you to say is that I want to pull my master branch and then FTP it to the server rather than performing the pull from the production server?